# Шаблонное продвижение типа

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть шаблонная функция, которая должна считать сумму двух значений одного типа. Как узнать (с помощью `<type_traits>`?) возвращаемый тип этой функции, чтобы он был таким, чтобы вмещать сумму этих значений? Например, для двух `long` в типичной реализации достаточно `long long`, чтобы вместить любую их сумму. Если реализация не поддерживает чего-то выше `std::int64_t`, то для двух значений этого типа вернуть его же. Можно ли как-то это сделать, не прописывая вручную кучу шаблонных специализаций?

```
template <typename T>
... sum(T left, T right); // как узнать возвращаемый тип?
```

Comment: Заметим вскользь :), что вполне может иметься реализация, где `sizeof(long long) == sizeof(long)`...

Comment: @Harry согласен, что ещё более усложняет ручную специализацию